# Http post method in ASP .Net programatically

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I want to write http post in mvc asp .net web service that takes a BasicNameValuePair from android application returns a Json Array.

Can you help guys ?

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public string change()
{

     int i=Request["id"] != null;
     System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer =
     new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
     string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(oList);
     return sJSON;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your asking, but it sounds like you want a endpoint which receives a list of key value pair and returns json. It can be done like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyMethod (IDictionary<string, object> inputParam) {
    var myArray = GetArrayFromSomewhere(inputParam); //possibly another webservice or database
    return Json(myArray, JsonRequestBehaviour.DenyGet);
}
```

Comment: can I insert a web service to asp .net mvc web application ?

Comment: You can use a endpoint like i suggested above accessing like this: /controller/mymethod  along with your dictionary post data.